# Properties stuck one level down

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am not having a problem so much with the query as accessing the data or setting it up so I can pass it to the view.

Here's the expression

```
  var distinctReplies = pd.Project.ProjectDoc
        .SelectMany(i => i.Comment
            .SelectMany(k => k.CommentReply
                .Select(u => u.User)
            ).Distinct()
        ).Select(g => new {FirstName = g.FirstName, LastName = g.LastName, UserID = g.UserID})
        .ToList();
```

After this expression I want to concat it with another one that is getting values from the same user model, I want to assign distinctReplies to a ViewBag variable and then be able to loop though it and do this
    `foreach (var user in @ViewBag.distinctReplies)` in a razor view.

However, to actually get at the values I have to do `distinctReplies.Select(i => i.FirstName)`. Not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create some ViewModel object for populating the query result. To be able to access the properties inside the `@foreach` loop.

**Model**

```
public class UserVM
{
    public int UserID{get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}  
}
```

**Updated query**

```
  var distinctReplies = ....
                .Select(g => new UserVM {FirstName = g.FirstName, 
                                         LastName = g.LastName, 
                                         UserID = g.UserID}).ToList();
```

Then, in the view, you will need to add cast to `IEnumerable<UserVM>`.

**View**

```
@foreach (var user in (IEnumerable<UserVM>) ViewBag.distinctReplies)
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I did, but it put me on the right track, I added a "User" model to the existing viewmodel and assigned it and that worked.

Comment: If you've created a model, then shouldn't be using ViewBag. Return the model set to the view: `return View("MyView", mymodelset);`.

Comment: Of course, better way would be to **not** putting it in `ViewBag` at all. And use strongly typed view.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@foreach (var reply in (IEnumerable)ViewBag.distinctReplies) 
{
}
```

You cannot enumerate an instance of a `dynamic`. Cast it to an `IEnumerable` for the statement to be allowed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939024/c-sharp-4-0-dynamic-and-foreach-statement) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: How would you acces the original properties of reply `object`?

Comment: You can't without reflection at this point. You should not use an anonymous type as your view model. Implement a ViewModel like suggested in @mipe34's answer. Then you can replace the `var` with `YourType`.