# Is it possible to iterate on List<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, dynamic

In the past few days I've been trying to find a way to iterate on a `List<dynamic>` without much success.

That's what I'm doing:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    dynamic e = new ExpandoObject();
    var d = e as IDictionary<string, object>;
    for (var i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        d.Add(dr.GetName(i), DBNull.Value.Equals(dr[i]) ? null : dr[i]);

    result.Add(e);
}
```

the above code is a method that returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` then in my controller I'm getting data back with:

```
dynamic irionErrorsExport = oracleDbManager.GetStrCtrlNDGWithErrors(tableName, queryParamsList, periodo, "", "", "");
```

and now I'm stuck since I need to iterate on irionErrorsExport and create a "concrete" object/s to use with EPPlus.

Can anyone please tell me if it is even possible and show a simple example?

Comment: Is `GetStrCtrlDGWithErrors()` your method that contains the first snippet of code?

Comment: Show us the `GetStrCtrlDGWithErrors` method signature

Comment: Note that you can do: `IDictionary<string, object> e = new ExpandoObject()`, change the `d.*` in `e.*` and then `result.Add(e)` without the intermediate cast.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can iterate over `dynamic` object:

```
dynamic source = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
foreach (var item in source)
{
    Console.Write(item.ToString());
}
```

Prints `123456` into console.

However, it will cause runtime exception if iteration is not possible:

Consider following code:

```
dynamic source = 2;
foreach (var item in source)
{
    Console.Write(item.ToString());
}
```

`RuntimeBinderException` is being thrown:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

***Edit***: you should be aware of the differences between `foreach` on *normal* variables and `dynamic`. They are explained in another SO question: [C# 4.0 'dynamic' and foreach statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939024/c-sharp-4-0-dynamic-and-foreach-statement)

Answer (score 1):

If you fill a `DataTable` like [here](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/406/filling-a-datatable-or-dataset-the-quick-way), You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and get a *concrete* object easily

```
//Sample DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("IntCol");
dt.Columns.Add("StrCol");
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{1,"1"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{2,"2"});

var jsonstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClass>>(jsonstr);

public class YourClass
{
    public int IntCol { set; get; }
    public string StrCol { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    IDictionary<string, object> e = new ExpandoObject();

    for (var i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        e.Add(dr.GetName(i), DBNull.Value.Equals(dr[i]) ? null : dr[i]);

    result.Add(e);
}
```

From the calling method you "cheat". You know that your dynamic collection is an `ExpandoObject`, so

```
foreach (IDictionary<string, object> row in result)
{
    foreach (var kv in row)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
}
```

In the end, it's better if your method simply returns a `List<IDictionary<string, object>>`, no `dynamic` necessary.

Reflection on dynamic types is hard. Unless you can use duck typing (duck typing is when you know that the object can `Duck()`, even if you don't know what exactly it's, so you can do `dynamic x = something; x.Duck();` ), then it's only semi-hard. If you don't trust me on this, you can try reading [How do I reflect over the members of dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2634858/613130)